# Silex Error loading Web profiler

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I got and an error when including the Web Profiler in a Silex 1.x  (pops up a 500 internal error):

> Neither the property "symfonyState" nor one of the methods "symfonyState()", "getsymfonyState()"/"issymfonyState()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\ConfigDataCollector" in "@WebProfiler/Collector/config.html.twig" at line 120

I have followed instructions: https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler/tree/1.0

I have registered in *app.php* the services as:

```
$app->register(new Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Provider\TwigServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider()); 

// test debug profiler
$app->register(new  Silex\Provider\WebProfilerServiceProvider(), array(
    'profiler.cache_dir' => __DIR__.'/../cache/profiler',
    'profiler.mount_prefix' => '/_profiler', // this is the default
));
```

What did I miss? How do I make it work?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using silex 1.x then you have to follow this instructions:

> composer require silex/web-profiler

Read more here:

[Using web-profiler with silex 1.x](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler/tree/1.0).

And if you are using silex 2.x then you have to follow this instructions:

> composer require 'silex/web-profiler:^2.0'

Read more here:

[Using web-profiler with silex 2.x](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler)